# Detox build command working locally but failing in Github Action

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, github-actions, detox

I have a `.detoxrc.json` with the following config:

```json
"apps": {
    "ios": {
      "type": "ios.app",
      "binaryPath": "./ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/<my-app-demo>.app",
      "build": "xcodebuild -workspace ios/<my-app>.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme '<my-app-demo>' -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build"
    }
},
```

This works fine locally, and I'm able to build and test successfully.

However, in github actions it fails every time. I've tried running the step as `yarn detox build -c ios` and as the actual command from the `"build"` instruction, but no luck.

Here's what I'm currently trying to do in the action's yml file:

```yaml
env:
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}

jobs:
  build:
    name: iOS Simulator Tests
    runs-on: macos-12
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 16
          cache: "yarn"

      - name: Cache node_modules
        id: cache
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: ./node_modules
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-modules-${{ hashFiles('yarn.lock') }}

      - name: Install node_modules
        if: steps.cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
        run: yarn install --frozen-lockfile

      - name: Pod Install
        run: cd ios && pod install && cd ..

      - name: Install Applesimutils
        run: |
          brew tap wix/brew
          brew install applesimutils

      - name: Detox build
        run: yarn detox build -c ios
      - name: Detox test
        run: yarn detox test -c ios --cleanup
```

Why would this not work on a github runner? As far as I know there's no special config I should need for this to run.

EDIT: Here are the logs that are outputting on failure:

```
2022-10-17T13:20:19.5286140Z error: /Users/runner/work/buyer-app/buyer-app/ios/my-app/main.jsbundle: No such file or directory (in target 'my-app Feat' from project 'my-app')
2022-10-17T13:20:19.5286460Z 
2022-10-17T13:20:19.5290650Z CpResource /Users/runner/work/buyer-app/buyer-app/ios/my-app/assets /Users/runner/work/buyer-app/buyer-app/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/my-app\ Feat.app/assets (in target 'my-app Feat' from project 'my-app')
2022-10-17T13:20:19.5292650Z     cd /Users/runner/work/buyer-app/buyer-app/ios
2022-10-17T13:20:19.5293830Z     builtin-copy -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -exclude .git -exclude .hg -resolve-src-symlinks /Users/runner/work/buyer-app/buyer-app/ios/my-app/assets /Users/runner/work/buyer-app/buyer-app/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/my-app\ Feat.app
2022-10-17T13:20:19.5294950Z error: /Users/runner/work/buyer-app/buyer-app/ios/my-app/assets: No such file or directory (in target 'my-app Feat' from project 'my-app')
2022-10-17T13:20:19.5295230Z 
2022-10-17T13:20:19.5296230Z CpResource /Users/runner/work/buyer-app/buyer-app/ios/my-app-Omega.ttf /Users/runner/work/buyer-app/buyer-app/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/my-app\ Feat.app/my-app-Omega.ttf (in target 'my-app Feat' from project 'my-app')
2022-10-17T13:20:19.5296910Z     cd /Users/runner/work/buyer-app/buyer-app/ios
2022-10-17T13:20:19.5297970Z     builtin-copy -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -exclude .git -exclude .hg -resolve-src-symlinks /Users/runner/work/buyer-app/buyer-app/ios/my-app-Omega.ttf /Users/runner/work/buyer-app/buyer-app/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/my-app\ Feat.app
2022-10-17T13:20:19.5298790Z 
2022-10-17T13:20:19.6324520Z ** BUILD FAILED **
2022-10-17T13:20:19.6324780Z 
2022-10-17T13:20:19.6324790Z 
2022-10-17T13:20:19.6325000Z The following build commands failed:
2022-10-17T13:20:19.6326500Z    CpResource /Users/runner/work/buyer-app/buyer-app/ios/my-app/main.jsbundle /Users/runner/work/buyer-app/buyer-app/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/my-app\ Feat.app/main.jsbundle (in target 'my-app Feat' from project 'my-app')
2022-10-17T13:20:19.6327810Z    CpResource /Users/runner/work/buyer-app/buyer-app/ios/my-app/assets /Users/runner/work/buyer-app/buyer-app/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/my-app\ Feat.app/assets (in target 'my-app Feat' from project 'my-app')
2022-10-17T13:20:19.6328290Z (2 failures)
2022-10-17T13:20:19.6446800Z 13:20:19.644 detox[12824] WARN:  [build.js] 
2022-10-17T13:20:19.6448980Z 
2022-10-17T13:20:19.6450160Z Important: 'detox build' is a convenience shortcut for calling your own build command, as provided in the config file.
2022-10-17T13:20:19.6451260Z Failures in this build command are not the responsibility of Detox. You are responsible for maintaining this command.
2022-10-17T13:20:19.6451830Z 
2022-10-17T13:20:19.6453150Z 13:20:19.644 detox[12824] ERROR: [cli.js] Command failed: xcodebuild -workspace ios/my-app.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme 'my-app Feat' -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build
2022-10-17T13:20:19.6455530Z 
2022-10-17T13:20:19.6647490Z error Command failed with exit code 1.
2022-10-17T13:20:19.6648170Z info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
2022-10-17T13:20:19.6746380Z ##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: Can you also include the details of the error it fails with?

Comment: thanks, but that just shows what command failed - there should be a piece of output that details the error

Comment: @MarekLisik I've added some more output from the end of the build logs, but the complete logs from github actions are 17MB (just logs, nothing else). So I can't really share that here. Is the above context enough to go on?

Comment: From the output you can see that one of the build phase script fails -- cannot find main.js.bundle and assets. Do you see the same issue if you change your detox config to use Release? (`"build": "xcodebuild -workspace ios/<my-app>.xcworkspace -configuration Release -scheme '<my-app-demo>' -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build"`)

Comment: @MarekLisik Haven't had the chance to do it in an action yet, but at least when I run Release locally and target the live scheme (rather than feat, which is the debug version) the build succeeds. Testing fails, but I think that's a version update issue: `RCTFatalException: Unhandled JS Exception: Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'DevSettings' could not be found. Verify that a module by this name is registered in the native binary.`